# 1-indexed Model in QCombobox

Tags: c++, qt

I have a 1-indexed (readonly-)model and want to use it for a combobox.
I parse the data (comes from a file-parser) and have for example:

*1: Variable Number 1* and that will be my first item, next 
*2: Variable Number 2* and so on.

When I click on an item the `currentIndex()`-method from QCombobox will give me a 0-indexed int, so my problem is:
I don't want to write everytime I parse a file +1 respectively -1 when writing back to the file (although the model is readonly, I can alter the data in the file). (I have nearly 30 UIs where I need the model, and for every UI I have to parse other data)

I currently use something like:

```
virtual int currentIndex() const { return QComboBox::currentIndex() + 1; }
virtual void setCurrentIndex(int index) { QComboBox::setCurrentIndex(index-1); }
```

I know that this is not ideal, because (set-)currentIndex is [not virtual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#properties). But to avoid +/-1 I used this for now. 
Does anybode have a good suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom model you could add a role that returns the "real" index value.

If you just use strings to fill the combobox, you could use the `setItemData()` and `itemData()` methods to associated your reference value.

E.g.

```
comboBox->addItem("Number 1", 1);
```

and

```
int refValue = comboBox->itemData(comboIndex).toInt();
```

The associated data can be anything that can be stored in a `QVariant`.

Comment: please, don't use backticks (`) for formatting code lines. Instead, indent your line with 4 spaces. :)

Comment: Maybe somebody should change the documentation then, it litst backticks as one of the options for code.

Comment: Backticks are used for inline code, not for blockcode ;)

Comment: Sorry, Kevin, I don't like this answer. I use the virtual `data` method to get the data and of course I could use that, but then I have to get the Qt::UserRole everytime I want the index, but that what's currentIndex is for (also I can't use setCurrentIndex in an easy way with your solution.).

Comment: I've edited the post but the block indentation made it necessary to put some text in between the two separate code lines otherwise it would have been just one block.
The backticks allow to have two code blocks without any artifical text in between

Comment: My answer was a suggestion on how to store a foreign reference data with each item, so that the foreign index/reference can be retrieved when the non-native system needs to be addressed.

Another option is to convert between the foreign and the C++ native indexes at loading/saving time

Comment: @punkkeks , the answer is far better than the *kludge* in your question. Overriding `currentIndex` and `setCurrentIndex` will get you to trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @punkkeks , for `setCurrentIndex`, you can use [`findData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#findData), to find the index and then use `setCurrentIndex`.

Comment: @punkkeks , I think that a `QComboBox` subclass is not the place to to translate your indexes. it would be better to translate those indexes in a separate class at loading/saving time as noted by Kevin. :)